# What is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, api, ibm-watson

i have some issue while using IBM Watson Speech to Text API on Android Studio. I Followed the instruction on `https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/develop/speech-to-text` .
This is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.w("debug_prog", "[+] Start");

    SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText("cff16fe4-6a27-4289-a343-a394e1c94c2x", "XStw1ieErTkx");
    if(service == null){
        Log.w("debug_prog", "[-] Service is null");

    }

    Log.w("debug_prog", "[+] Object Created");


    File audio = new File("src/test/resources/audio_001.wav");
    Log.w("debug_prog", "[+] Audio: " + String.valueOf(audio));

    SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio).execute();
    Log.w("debug_prog", "[+] Result: " + String.valueOf(transcript));

}
```

}

but when i compiled the code on Android Phone (API 22) i got some error like this:

```
08-10 21:46:05.367 12047-12047/com.example.albertus.speechtotext E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.albertus.speechtotext, PID: 12047
                                                                               java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                   at com.example.albertus.speechtotext.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:975)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'
                                                                                   at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePatternCharacter(SimpleDateFormat.java:314)
                                                                                   at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:303)
                                                                                   at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:356)
                                                                                   at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:249)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.DateDeserializer.<init>(DateDeserializer.java:52)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton.registerTypeAdapters(GsonSingleton.java:53)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton.createGson(GsonSingleton.java:42)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton.getGsonWithoutPrettyPrinting(GsonSingleton.java:76)
                                                                                   at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.SpeechToText.<clinit>(SpeechToText.java:119)
                                                                                   at com.example.albertus.speechtotext.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:164) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:975) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

this Error happened when i create SpeechToText object, Please Help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

ErrorInitializerException is thrown if some static resource or block have an error.

But in your case you trying to run java library in android which probably doesn't work.

Try changing api version or download example from their github:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/tree/master/example